# how to get checkout cart specific item totat price?

Tags: magento, checkout

I have a custom html I want to implement this html into checkout cart page . I have implement it but i cant get cart item total price , eg. I have 5 item in cart . I have updated only one specific item in the cart then I don’t get these specific item total price .

default item $50 *1 =$50

After Update quantity

item price : $50 * 2 = ??(I want to get total of this specific item ).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the price as:

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item) {
       $qty = $item->getQty();
       $price = $item->getPrice();
       $totalPrice =  $qty * $price; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get cart item specific details, you can use :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
   $qty = $item->getQty() ;
   $price = $item->getPrice();
   $totalPrice =  $qty * $price; 
}
```

Comment: you can get this from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

i am using default magento functionality to get specific item price in magento chekout cart page

```
<?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
    <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal() + $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount() + $_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```